# Magento : Display all products with their Categories on Home Page

Tags: magento, product

I need to display all the Products assigned to Categories on Home Page of my website like below.

```
Category A      Category B      Category C          
----------      -----------     ----------              
Product A       Product B       Product C
```

In CMS > Home Page > Content section I have included the block

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="homeproduct_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Here **catalog/product/list.phtml** is the default Magento **list.phtml** without any modifications.

My products are displayed on Home Page only if I assign any product to a Category as well as **Default Category (Root Category)**

```
For ex: Product A is assigned to Default Category (Root) and Categopry A as well
```

If I assign the product only to a Category (which I want) then it does not show any products on Home Page.

The issue here is not this one [How to display ALL PRODUCTS in the homepage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253389/magento-how-to-display-all-products-in-the-homepage) but why is that I have to assign product to **Default Category (Root)** also in order to display it on home page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you have look into database table `catalog_category_entity` it will store all category id like  **first must be root category/subcategory/subcategory[if]** and when you fetch so,you have to first must assign root category then its subcategory

```
$product->getCategoryIds() it will get all category id please check image
```

[image]

Comment: Fetching Category on prod detail page will be easy and direct while to fetch it on Home Page I need to use 

$_product->getCategoryIds() and load categories via array key i.e. 0/1/2