# Magento - How to list all products in one category on one page

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to list all the products in one category without having to set a global setting in Magento `1.7`. I have `max` products per page set as `25`. In one category there are `28` products and it is being split in to `2` pages. I would like to set an exception for this one category and list all of its products in one page. I've managed to find layout update xml code that allows me to list all the products for a certain category on the home page:
[Magento - How to display ALL PRODUCTS in the homepage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253389/magento-how-to-display-all-products-in-the-homepage)

But this doesn't work when placed using the update xml for a category. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to Catalog->Manage Categories .Choose the particular category and select the tab **Custom Design** and add the below xml snippet to the field **Custom Layout Update**

```html
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
   <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>28</limit></action>
</reference>
```

You can change display mode to either as **grid** or **list** based on your theme.

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are configuration options under System > Configuration > Catalog for setting the qty options available in product lists. There's also an option to enable showing all items, and these apply to search pages.